# Alinhar itens na pagina html

Tags: html, css

Tenho o seguinte código:

*CSS:*

```
.apoio{
   float:left;
} 

.box{
   width:300px;
   height:100px;
   background-color:#666;
   border-radius: 10px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

*HTML:*

```
<canvas class="apoio" id="cvs" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
<div class="box"></div>
```

A ideia era que ambos ficassem um do lado do outro, porém...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para deixa-los paralelos e não dessa forma?

**EDIT 1:**
Dentro do canvas tenho um javascript:

```
<script>
window.onload = function ()
{
    var data = {}
        data.shipped = [<?php echo $mes_quant[$b]; ?>];
        data.sold    = [<?php echo $hoje_quant[$b]; ?>];

    var bar1 = new RGraph.Bar({
        id: 'cvs',
        data: data.shipped,
        options: {
            gutterTop: 40,
            gutterLeft: 70,
            colors: ['rgba(0,0,255,0.2)'],
            labels: ['Acessos Hoje/Mês'],
            labelsAbove: data.shipped,
            strokestyle: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            scaleZerostart: true,
            textAccessible: true,
            shadow: true
        }
    }).draw();

    var bar2 = new RGraph.Bar({
        id: 'cvs',
        data: data.sold,
        options: {
            ymax: bar1.scale2.max,
            gutterTop: 40,
            gutterLeft: bar1.Get('gutterLeft'),
            colors: ['pink'],
            noaxes: true,
            labelsAbove: true,
            hmargin: 20,
            ylabels: false,
            backgroundGrid: false,
            strokestyle: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            textAccessible: true,
            shadow: true
        }
    }).draw();
};
</script>
```

**Edit 2**

```
 <canvas class="apoio" id="cvs" width="500" height="200" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: inline; float: none;"></canvas>
```

Comment: `float:left` no box não resolve?

Comment: a <div>  ficou no lugar do <canvas> dessa forma

Comment: Tentou colocar float:right no box cinza? Com esse CSS não consegui simular exatamente o seu erro

Comment: Sim, mas preciso que eles fiquem um do lado do outro, to grafico do lado esquerdo e o box no meio, porém, quando centralizo o box, ele fica no meio e abaixo do grafico como na imagem que eu postei

Comment: Poste uma amostra do conteúdo do canvas. Ele pode estar jogando o box pra baixo.

Comment: @dvd, atualizei

Comment: Mas assim não tem como reproduzir. Tem que colocar o HTML do canvas depois de renderizado. Vai no "inspecionar elementos" do navegador e copie tupo de que tiver dentro da tag <canvas>.

Comment: Vai no "inspecionar elementos", localize a tag do <canvas> e clique com o botão direito do mouse e escolha "Copy > Copy outerHTML", depois cola na pergunta.

Comment: @dvd, atualizei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vejo que você usa um plugin chamado **[RGraph](https://www.rgraph.net/install/getting-started-with-rgraph.html)**. Esse plugin cria uma `div` contâiner com `id` `#cvs_rgraph_domtext_wrapper`.

Logo, no seu CSS, defina o `float: left;` para essa `div`:

```
#cvs_rgraph_domtext_wrapper{
   float:left;
}
```

**Print:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Era isso msm cara valeu :D

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é exatamente isso que vc quer, mas com display:flex da pra fazer algo assim. Acredito que pode resolver seu problema.

O Box Cinza sempre vai ficar no centralizado no espaço que sobrar depois do box Vermelho

```css
body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 display: flex;
 align-items: flex-start;
}
.apoio{
  float:left;
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
 } 
 .box{
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#666;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

```html
<canvas class="apoio" id="cvs" ></canvas>
<div class="box"></div>
```